# using has_one, has_many, and many_many in controller/to filter queries

Tags: silverstripe

I have watched lesson 7 - lesson 10 videos on the silverstripe.org website, have read all the articles on this page: http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/, been all up in the API and have googled silverstripe/stackoverflow forums for hours. I am really stuck trying to apply what I learned though. Here is what I'm trying to do. I want to expand on the Article Holder & Article Page concept. I am trying to make another page that is a Master Article Holder and my site tree will be organized as such:

```
HomePage
   |
   | _ MasterArticleHolderOne
   |      |
   |      | _ ArticleHolderA
   |      |      |
   |      |      | _ ArticlePageA1
   |      |      |
   |      |      | _ ArticlePageA2
   |      |      |          
   |      |      | _ ArticlePageA3
   |      |
   |      |
   |      | _ ArticleHolderB
   |      |      |
   |      |      | _ ArticlePageB1
   |      |      |
   |      |      | _ ArticlePageB2
   |      |      |          
   |      |      | _ ArticlePageB3
   |      |
   |      |
   |      | _ ArticleHolderB
   |             |
   |             | _ ArticlePageB1
   |             |
   |             | _ ArticlePageB2
   |             |          
   |             | _ ArticlePageB3
   |       
   | _ MasterArticleHolderTwo
```

I would like the MasterArticleHolder page to do is this: There will be an option in the CMS for the MasterArticleHolder page to select any existing ArticleHolder pages (meaning that even MasterArticleHolderTwo from above could display articles from ArticleHolderA or B or C) and the MasterArticleHolder page will then display all the articles that are children of the selected ArticleHolder pages. These articles need to be sorted by PublicationDate; not grouped by what holder they belong to.

Here is the code that I've written so far. The ArticlePage and the ArticleHolder work perfectly. It's the MasterArticleHolder that I'm struggling with (though I did manage to at least create checkboxes appear in the CMS for all existing ArticleHolder page, don't know if it will actually function once everything else is written):

ArticlePage

```
class ArticlePage extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'PublicationDate' => 'Date',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', DateField::create('PublicationDate','Publication Date')->setConfig('showcalendar', true));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

ArticleHolder

```
class ArticleHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function LatestArticles() {
        return ArticlePage::get()
            ->filter('PublicationDate:LessThanOrEqual', SS_Datetime::now())
            ->sort('PublicationDate', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

MasterArticleHolder

```
class MasterArticleHolder extends Page {

    private static $many_many = array (
        'Categories' => 'ArticleHolder'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', CheckboxSetField::create(
            'Categories',
            'Articles to Display',
            ArticleHolder::get()->map('ID','MenuTitle')
        ));

        return $fields;
    }

}
class MasterArticleHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function LatestArticles() {
        return ArticlePage::get()
            ->filter(array('PublicationDate:LessThanOrEqual' => SS_Datetime::now()))
            ->sort('PublicationDate', 'DESC')
    }
}
```

Seems to me that there could be the following relations but I just don't know which one is needed, if any

- ArticlePage is a has_one with ArticleHolder
- ArticleHolder is a has_many with ArticlePage
- ArticleHolder is a many_many with MasterArticleHolder (Don't really know which one is the belongs_many_many but I'd guess Article Holder)

The following relation may also apply but they seem less likely to me

- ArticlePage is a many_many with MasterArticleHolder

Now I know normally the the has_one, has_many, and many_many apply to objects that extend DataObject but I figured that since page in a round-about way extends DataObject that these relationships may still apply, but I could be completely wrong and really overthinking things.

Hopefully I explained myself well enough for me to get help, but not too much to overwhelm everyone. I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to go further into the tutorials, this (using Pages) is ... not really the best solution. It can work, but is extremely complex and just not really a good idea.

If you're doing this as a learning exercise then that's cool, but if not then just use the Blog Module http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/blog - it does basically exactly this.

It would be better to use DataObjects instead of Pages for this exercise. See video tutorial 9 (http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-has-many)

A simple solution to what you've got now though is:

```
ArticlePage::get()
  ->filter([
    'ParentID'=>$this->Categories()->getIDList(),
    'PublicationDate:LessThanOrEqual'=>'now'
  ])
  ->sort('PublicationDate','desc');
```

Basically:  get every Article that's parent is one of my chosen categories (then your existing filters, sort, etc).

Using DataObjects instead of Pages is basically the same thing (Pages are DataObjects), but you get less pollution of the site tree (in the CMS) and hierarchical issues to do with children, etc.

But then on the other hand you loose the automatic routing, and various other things that Page gives you. This is why the Blog module is a much better solution if you're not just trying to learn.

Comment: I figured there was a module for what I'm trying to do but a lot of what I'm doing now with silverstripe is trying to learn and understand the framework. It's why I chose it over wordpress or joomla. I don't want to just plug in code and have it magically work, I would first like to understand how everything actually fits together, and even build some crappy version of the modules myself to further my understanding.  Seems like silverstripe is great for that. Their documentation is fantastic. As far as your answer though, I'll try it later tonight when I get the chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have the time to test these but following should work.. as a guide at least:

Remove the

```
  private static $many_many = array (
        'Categories' => 'ArticleHolder'
    );
```

and add categories as a db field

```
private static $db = array(
    'Categories' => 'Varchar'
);
```

No need to introduce a new relation as they are already Children of that holder. The checkbox field set stores the data as comma separated list. This is a loose relation so note that.

Then use the comma separated list in the filter with something like:

```
public function LatestArticles() {
$ids = explode(",", $this->Categories)

        return ArticlePage::get()
            ->filter(array('ParentID' => $ids))
            ->sort('PublicationDate', 'DESC')
    }
```

I just cant remember is the database field parent_id or ParentID or what so that you might want to check out from the database tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try this later tonight when I get the chance!